# Why is "to accept" used in "I was happy to accept the appointment”?

Tags: adjectives, infinitives, exam-questions

> I was happy ________ the appointment.

A. **to accept**

B. **to be accepting**

C. **to have accepted**

D. **accepting**

The given answer is **to accept**

Whether an infinitive should follow the adjective **happy**?

Why are other options not correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Happy to accept" is the idiomatic use. In the sense of "content or satisfied" the usage is either

> ... happy to (do something)

> ... happy with (something)

The first three use this pattern.  But there is no need to use a continuous or perfect form.  The perfect would suggest that you were satisfied with the consequences of acceptance; not ungrammatical but not the usual expression.

The last one has a different sense of "happy", it means "cheerful or experiencing enjoyment".  It says the process of accepting the appointment made you feel cheerful, or that you were in a good mood while you were accepting the appointment.  Again, not ungrammatical, but probably not the intended meaning.

All four could find some use, but certainly (A) is by far the most likely.

Comment: I really wish that the people coming up with these test questions did a better job of making the "wrong" answers actually ungrammatical, instead of merely unidiomatic. Unless this is *supposed* to be a high-level "can you speak it like a native speaker" test.